# laravel 5.8: show empty fields to a new user in profile page

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-5, profile

I am setting up profile section.

> I want to show empty fields to a new user.

First I tried this, but it didn't work because new user's profile table is empty.

```
<li>Name :<br>
    <p>
      {{ Auth::user()->profile->name }}
    </p>
 </li>
```

So next I tried this one.

```
<p>@if(!empty(Auth::user()->profile->name))
      {{ Auth::user()->profile->name }}
    @endif</p>
```

It worked, I could see an empty field with no error. But after I inserted a 'name' and redirect to index.blade.php page, 'name' didn't show up, still empty.

> I want to see a profile page filled with user profile information.

Then, lastly, I tried this.

```
@if($profile->count() > 0)
    <ul class="information">
        <li>Name :<br>
           <p>
             {{ Auth::user()->profile->name }}
           </p>
         </li><br>
@endif
```

but I got an error **Undefined variable: profile.**

**UserController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $profile = new Profile;

        $profile->name = $request->input('name');

        $profile->save();

        return redirect()->route('profile.index');

    }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::prefix('user')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('profile', 'UserController');
});
```

also I want to show profile information to an edit page.

I am glad if someone helps me out.

Answer (score 1):

In UserController,

```
public function index()
    {
       $profiles=Profile::all()
        return view('your_view_file_path', compact('profiles'));
    }
```

In Blade

```
@foreach($profiles as $profile)
<li>Name :<br>
           <p>
             {{profile->name}}
           </p>
         </li><br>
@enforeach
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. But I got an syntax error ->.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change :

```
return redirect()->route('profile.index');
```

To :

```
return redirect()->route('profile.index', [$profile]);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply keeping name values to input tag so you can pass all values. maybe that can be issue?

```
@if($profile->count() > 0)
    <ul class="information">
        <li>Name :<br>
           <input type="text" name="name1" value="
             {{ Auth::user()->profile->name }}" />
         </li><br>
@endif
```

Inside your Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $profile = new Profile;

        $profile->name = $request->input('name1');

        $profile->save();

        return redirect()->route('profile.index');

    }
```